# MySQL result with multiple occurance of an element depending on importance

Tags: mysql, arrays, random, sql-order-by

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to fetch a list of mysql entries depending on the importance of each row. Lets say I have 4 entries in a table (id, name, importance). 0 = highest importance.

```
id | file      | importance
---|-----------|-----------
1  | movie.mp4 | 0
2  | image.jpg | 1
3  | movie1.mp4| 2
4  | movie2.mp4| 2
```

want to create a array with 20 enteries, which are populized with result from the 4 elements (example 5*movie.mp4, 3*image.jpg, 2*..., 2*...), but the trick is the elements must be randomly placed in the array and not after each other.

```
$file[] = movie.mp4;
$file[] = movie2.mp4;
$file[] = image.jpg;
$file[] = movie.mp4;
$file[] = image.jpg;
$file[] = movie1.mp4;
$file[] = movie.mp4;
$file[] = image.jpg;
$file[] = movie.mp4;
$file[] = movie1.mp4;
$file[] = movie.mp4;
$file[] = movie2.jpg;
```

Hope you get the point, or else please ask :)

Comment: Please rephrase your question title, it has nothing to do with the description you have provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT draw_bucket.file
FROM (
    SELECT row,
    FLOOR( RAND() * ( SELECT SUM( POW( 2, 2 - importance ) ) FROM files ) ) AS rnd
    FROM ( 
       (SELECT 1 AS row) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3) UNION (SELECT 4) UNION
       (SELECT 5) UNION (SELECT 6) UNION (SELECT 7) UNION (SELECT 8) UNION
       (SELECT 9) UNION (SELECT 10) UNION (SELECT 11) UNION (SELECT 12) UNION
       (SELECT 13) UNION (SELECT 14) UNION (SELECT 15) UNION (SELECT 16) UNION
       (SELECT 17) UNION (SELECT 18) UNION (SELECT 19) UNION (SELECT 20)
    ) AS row_nums
) AS rows
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row, file
    FROM ( 
       (SELECT 1 AS cnt) UNION (SELECT 2) UNION (SELECT 3) UNION (SELECT 4)
    ) AS cnt
    INNER JOIN files
    ON( cnt.cnt <= POW( 2, 2 - files.importance ) )
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT @row := -1 ) AS INIT
) AS draw_bucket
ON( rows.rnd = draw_bucket.row )
```

number of `(SELECT 1), (SELECT 2), ...` in the `row_nums` subquery should equal the number of entries you want and in `cnt` subquery should equal 2 ^ minimumPriority.

You can simplify this by doing most of the job in PHP (for example). Do a `SELECT *` and fill an array like this:

```
$items = array(
    array( 'file' => 'movie.mp4', 'importance' => 0 ),
    array( 'file' => 'image.jpg', 'importance' => 1 ),
    array( 'file' => 'movie1.mp4', 'importance' => 2 ),
    array( 'file' => 'movie2.mp4', 'importance' => 2 )
);
```

Then do the drawing in PHP:

```
$minImportance = 2;

$drawBucket = array();
foreach( $items as $index => $item ) {
    for( $i = 0; $i < pow( 2, $minImportance - $item['importance'] ); ++$i ) {
        $drawBucket[] = $index;
    }
}

$output = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < 20; ++$i ) {
    $randomIndex = mt_rand( 0, count($drawBucket) - 1 );
    $output[] = $items[ $drawBucket[$randomIndex] ][ 'file' ];
}

var_dump( $output );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
This creates the array yes, but it does not take the most important files with each time. The goal is to have the important files showing up in the array more oftan than anything else at the time that the array is created and switch the files, so the same file doesn't come right after again.

Comment: @Fløtti It does exactly what you want, important files show up more often, look more closely, we put more of the important files in the draw_bucket, both codes are tested.

Comment: Yeah, I can see it does take the important files after I ran it several times. The only issue now, is to make sure that it doesn't print out the same file out twice for example as "element 3 and 4".

Comment: @Fløtti That would be almost impossible to incorporate into the MySql code but in the PHP code add a variable to the second loop to track the previously drawn file and if it is the same as the current file draw again until it is not the same.

Comment: thank you, now I created a fench post solution to ensure to get the first entry and go over the rest of the elements.

This is how I did:
$output = array();
$randomIndex = mt_rand( 0, count($drawBucket) - 1 );
$output[0] = $items[ $drawBucket[$randomIndex] ][ 'name' ];
for( $i = 1; $i < 20; ++$i ) {
 $previous = $output[$i-1];
    while($items[ $drawBucket[$randomIndex] ][ 'name' ] == $previous){
     $randomIndex = mt_rand( 0, count($drawBucket) - 1 );
    }
    $output[] = $items[ $drawBucket[$randomIndex] ][ 'name' ];
}

Answer (score 0):

We can do it simple with php:

```
<?php
function cmpf(a,b)
{
    return a['importance'] - b['importance'];
}
$arr = array();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbname ORDER BY importance;");
$k = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  $arr[$k] = $row;
  $k++
}
shuffle($arr);
usort($arr, "cmpf");
?>
```